# How to convert output of var_dump to array or variable?

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I am trying to take difference of two time. I have used diff function for that and now I want to transfer output of var_dump to array or variable so that I am able to print remaining time. My code is written below. **How to retrieve below output to array or variable?**

```
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09';

$var2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);

$datetime2 = new DateTime($val2);

var_dump($datetime1->diff($datetime2));
```

**My output is show below**

```
object(DateInterval)#3 (8) {

  ["y"]=>
  int(0)

  ["m"]=>
  int(11)

  ["d"]=>
  int(1)

  ["h"]=>
  int(6)

  ["i"]=>
  int(17)

  ["s"]=>
  int(23)

  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)

  ["days"]=>
  int(338)

}
```

Comment: What do you think `var_dump()` does?

Comment: If you need to assign diff array into variable, just do it: `$diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2)`.

Comment: [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is a debugging aid. It is not supposed to be used in production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you have to write following it will return array.

```
$data = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);  //Return Object
$data = (array) $datetime1->diff($datetime2);  //Return Array
```

**Object Output**

```
$data->y = 0  //year
$data->m = 11 //month 
$data->d = 1  //day
$data->h = 1  //hour
$data->i = 8  //minute
$data->s = 33 //second
```

**Array Output**

```
$data['y'] = 0  //year
$data['m'] = 11 //month 
$data['d'] = 1  //day
$data['h'] = 1  //hour
$data['i'] = 8  //minute
$data['s'] = 33 //second
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nzmk9O)**

Comment: I want all this as array

Comment: You can use `second` answer in my code `$data = (array) $datetime1->diff($datetime2);`

Answer (score 1):

You use function `date()` to format the current time then pass the result to the constructor of class [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) that parses the date to components just to get back the current timestamp.

There is no need make it do this hard work. If you need a `DateTime` object that contains the current date & time all you need to do is to create a new instance of `DateTime` and pass no parameters to its [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php):

```
$datetime2 = new DateTime();
```

Now, about the difference between two dates. Using [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) is the correct way to do it, indeed, but using `var_dump()` doesn't help and converting it to array (or other strange things) is not needed.

The value returned by `DateTime::diff()` is an object of type [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). It provides public access to its properties and it also provides you the method [`DateInterval::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) that is a nice way to produce readable string out of the value it encapsulates.

```
$val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09';
$datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime('now');

$diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo("It's been ".$diff->days.' days since '.$val1.".\n");
echo($diff->format("%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds to be more precise.\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you still need to manipulate this variable, so I would suggest that you assign the return value to a variable, instead of trying to get the string value from var_dump.

> `$diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2)` - as per @panther.

If your goal is to capture the string output, then you can use `$valueInString = print_r($diff, true);` although its output is slightly different from var_dump.

P.S. I think you misspelled `$var2` as it should be `$val2`